# VBA vlookup in another sheet

Tags: vba, macros

I have two Sheets (Sheet1 & Sheet2). Sheet2 has list of headers with numbers either as 1 or 3 in adjacent cells. Sheet 1 has same headers with values as "TRUE" or "FALSE" from columns A to D. I want that if all values in a row of A:D is "FALSE", column E should return 0. If any of the cells contains "TRUE", do a vlookup from sheet2 using headers and return the number adjacent to each header listed in sheet2.
I have written a code which is working fine however, it returns the same number for all the rows what's there in the first row of sheet2. Can you please suggest where the error is. Attached image shows output I am getting. Ideally last row should return 1 instead of 3.

[image: Sample from both Sheets]

```
Sub UpdateOutput()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim headersRange As Range
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim outputRange As Range
    Dim headersCell As Range
    Dim dataRow As Range
    Dim lookupValue As String
    Dim lookupResult As Variant
    Dim lr As Long
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QMform")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NameList")
    Set headersRange = ws2.Range("A2:B5")
    
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lr
    Set dataRange = ws1.Range("A" & i & ":D" & i)
    Set outputRange = ws1.Range("E" & i & ":E" & i)
    
    For Each dataRow In dataRange.Rows

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dataRow, "TRUE") = 0 Then
            outputRange.Cells(dataRow.Row - dataRange.Row + 1).Value = 0
        Else
            For Each headersCell In headersRange
                lookupValue = headersCell.Value
                
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dataRow, "TRUE") > 0 Then
                    lookupResult = Application.Vlookup(lookupValue, headersRange.Offset(0, 1), 2, False)

                    If Not IsError(lookupResult) Then

                        outputRange.Cells(dataRow.Row - dataRange.Row + 1).Value = lookupResult
                    End If
                End If
            Next headersCell
        End If
      Next dataRow
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: @Brian I have written codes here. Please check complete question.

Comment: ...and it is the exact same code and question as the post yesterday. Therefore, it is a duplicate.